# no flash content Scale in projector screen

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash

I have a flash animation with the screen dimension of 1024px by 768px.
The flash is having all vector graphics.
I want to fit the animation in full-screen when I publish exe. Which I am able to do with fscommand.
I am getting an issue when I run the exe file the flash content doesn't scale according to the screen. It shows the white area around the animation content.

Is there any possibility that I can make the flash content area fit to full-screen when I publish it to exe.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
```

Also see for other scaling options: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html